# src/hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Tags: hibernate

I am using hiberante 4. when I try to create my Factory connection I get this error.

```
Testlog4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.HibernateException: src/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Test
```

my **hibernate.cfg.xml** looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.Postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">test</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">target/indexes</property>
        <mapping class="org.mark.dto.UserDetails"/>
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and my test class reads like this.

```
package org.mark.dto;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.mark.usr.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    
     private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;  
        private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;  
      
        public static void main(String[] args){  
              
      
            UserDetails user= new UserDetails();  
                user.setUserId(1);  
                user.setUserName("Test");  
            System.out.print("Test");  
                try{  
      
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();  
                configuration.configure("src/hibernate.cfg.xml");  
                serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();  
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);  
                Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();  
                session.beginTransaction();  
                session.save(user);  
                session.getTransaction().commit();  
                }catch (HibernateException ex) {  
                    System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);  
      
                }  finally {  
                    System.out.print("Test");  
                }  
        }  

}
```

I am using Hibernate 4. my config file is directly under my src folder. not sure why its not being detected.

When path is changed to  configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

This error show

```
Testlog4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" Testjava.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/search/util/logging/impl/LoggerFactory
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:76)
    at org.mark.dto.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/search/util/logging/impl/LoggerFactory
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.<clinit>(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.search.util.logging.impl.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

Jars Used:
[image]

Comment: What folders do you have? In what folder is that HibernateTest.java file?

Comment: HibernateTest.java. It is in src/org.mark.dto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, it doesn't really matter where the file is in your IDE. All it counts is where the file will be during execution time, in the final bundle (probably a generated jar, in your case).

So, assuming from the info you already gave, your `src/` folder should become the root of the executed bundle (jar). This way, as `hibernate.cfg.xml` is in `src/`, then it should be in the root (of the jar) during execution time. In other words:

Instead of:

```
configuration.configure("src/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Use:

```
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

### Update:

For the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.search.util.logging.impl.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    ...
```

We can see that the class `org.hibernate.search.util.logging.impl.LoggerFactory` is missing from your classpath. Judging from the jars you already have, the missing one can be found in this link: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-search-engine/4.4.0.CR1/hibernate-search-engine-4.4.0.CR1.jar

Comment: I added the trace up top. Not sure if im missing a jar or something.

Comment: jars listed above. pretty much all the required jars for hibernate 4.

Comment: Hi. Try downloading this jar: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-search-engine/4.4.0.CR1/hibernate-search-engine-4.4.0.CR1.jar and adding it to the project.

Comment: That worked thanks. I had to also add commons-collection-3.2.1.jar and classmate-0.5.4.jar. Then I needed to added the postgres jar into the Hibernate Library just for precautions. I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can load hibernate.cfg.xml from a different directory (not necessarily the classpath) using the configure(File configFile) method that takes the hibernateConfig File argument.
(note, am using hibernate 4.3.7)

The advantage is, if you have no access to the war file but can get access to the hibernate file in a different directory, say for maintenance.

Like this:

---

```
String hibernatePropsFilePath = "/etc/configs/hibernate.cfg.xml";
File hibernatePropsFile = new File(hibernatePropsFilePath);

Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); 
configuration.configure(hibernatePropsFile);

StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();

SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

---